# PHP Form check if PHP x + y > z before submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, form-submit

I have the following variables:

```
$aantalcompleet
$ready
$totaalaantal
```

`$aantalcompleet` is a value get from DB.

`$totaalaantal` is also a value get from DB.

`$ready` is the value get from the form.

I want to check if $aantalcompleet + $ready > $totaalaantal before submit the form.

If this sum is TRUE, I want to get a confirm message with "Continue or Cancel".
If the sum is FALSE, the form can sumbit without message.

my form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="reset_form" value="Reset Form" onclick="this.form.reset();"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
    </span>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="complete" id="complete" value="" placeholder="0">
      <input type="hidden" name="machine" value="<?php echo $machine;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="base" value="<?php echo $base;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="<?php echo $lot;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="split" value="<?php echo $split;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="sub" value="<?php echo $sub;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="seq" value="<?php echo $seq;?>">
  </div>
</div>
  <button class="btn btn-default" style="height:35px;width:200px" type="submit" value="gereed" name="gereed">Gereed</button>
```

Comment: Hello! Do you have any code to show how you have attempted this solution?

Comment: Before form submit either do ajax(if your calculation depends upon server) or check in javascript.

Comment: It's better to use Javascript  instead of  PHP

Comment: use `ajax` for checking before form submit.

Comment: @SomnathMondal there's no reason to use Ajax here.  The check can easily be done in client-side JS, so the user gets instant feedback on if the form is valid, BEFORE the data is sent to the server. (Of course you still need to validate on the server-side as well.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, I understand.. Thanks

Comment: @party-ring I used PHP to check if the sum was greather than $totaalaantal. I gave it an alert and didn't do anything with it, but now I want to give them a choice to continue with the form submitting or cancel and fill in again. 

I tried a simular script as Emre Erdogan posted here, but also not the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your page somewhere in `<head>`

```html
<script>
function onsubmit(event){
    if($aantalcompleet + $ready > $totaalaantal){
        if(!confirm('Continue or Cancel')){
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Assuming your PHP variables `$aantalcompleet`, `$totaalaantal`, and `$ready` are available in the same file with your form, place the following code to a place where those variables have their expected values (i.e. they are filled with the values from database, maybe just after your sql query if any)

```
<script>
    var $aantalcompleet = <?php echo $aantalcompleet; ?>;
    var $totaalaantal = <?php echo $totaalaantal; ?>;  
    var $ready = <?php echo $ready; ?>;
</script>
```

Then add `onsubmit="return onsubmit(event)"` to your form tag, like

`<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return onsubmit(event)">`

Comment: The form is still submitting without confirm message

Comment: @RicoKrouweel Can you open your browsers dev tool console and check the values of $aantalcompleet, $totaalaantal, $ready JavaScript variables? Are they ok? Any errors on console?

Comment: Error: Maximum call stack size exceed
at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Comment: @RicoKrouweel I've updated the answer based on some assumptions. Can you check it out and try again?

Comment: Still the same as before